# Microsoft SHA256 Hash Gives "Incorrect" value for string.empty

Tags: c#, encryption, hash

I don't know if it's a "spec" or generally agreed upon or linux or just google, but many sites say that the SHA256 hash for an empty string is e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855 or base64
"ZTNiMGM0NDI5OGZjMWMxNDlhZmJmNGM4OTk2ZmI5MjQyN2FlNDFlNDY0OWI5MzRjYTQ5NTk5MWI3ODUyYjg1NQ=="

However, given the following code in C#

```
    using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        var contentBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        byte[] hashedBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(contentBytes);
        var hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
        return hash;
    }
```

the base64 value of hash where content=string.empty or content="" will be "47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU="

Why the difference?

Comment: That base64 string cannot be equivalent to that hex, as the base64 is longer (and should be shorter). The base64 of SHA256(empty) is `47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=`

Comment: In the first part you have base64 encoded the **hex** value rather than the binary value. Both examples produce the same hash `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`.

Comment: Since this question is based on misinterpretation of strings and byte arrays and unrelated to title at all, I voted to close as "typo"... Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa which may help to clarify things (along with the answer posted here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You're most likely seeing a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) being emitted from the UTF8 encoder.</s>

Edit: Maybe not. This works for me:

```cs
var content = string.Empty;
using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
    var contentBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    byte[] hashedBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(contentBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-","").ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

Output:

`e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

The "ZTNiMG..." is the Base64 representation of the **string** "e3b0c..." and not the **bytes** `e3 b0 c4...`. So the "47DEQ..." is actually **correct**.

If you insist on the "ZTNiMG..." string then use this:

```cs
var content = string.Empty;
using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
    var contentBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    byte[] hashedBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(contentBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-","").ToLowerInvariant())));
}
```

Output:
`ZTNiMGM0NDI5OGZjMWMxNDlhZmJmNGM4OTk2ZmI5MjQyN2FlNDFlNDY0OWI5MzRjYTQ5NTk5MWI3ODUyYjg1NQ==`